How to fuse a continuous reward value with multiple discrete rewards
There is a continuous reward and many discrete rewards. These rewards need to be merged into a new reward A. This reward A is designed as a weight to compute the weighted log-loss. In the past, I get the sum of the continuous reward and those discrete rewards. The trained results will tend to favor these discrete rewards.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
